# Возможно ли использовать значение подзапросов в текущем запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, есть подобный SQL - запрос:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
        FROM leads_fields 
        WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244991 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        as 'coefRL',
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
        FROM leads_fields 
        WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244943 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        as 'coefWF'

FROM leads
```

И для того,чтобы получить разницу этих значений мне необходимо дублировать эти запросы 3-им подзапросом вот так?

```
(
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
     FROM leads_fields 
     WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244991 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        -
     (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
      FROM leads_fields 
      WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244943 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
) as 'sum'
```

Или есть способы по-практичнее, вроде `(coefRL - coefWF)` ?

Comment: `select coefRL, coefWF, coefRL - coefWF from (select (select ...)  coefRL, (select ...) coefWF from leads) X`

Comment: Хотя можно было проще, вообще без подзапросов в списке выборки, но без знания структуры таблиц и данных вариантов предлагать не буду. Плюс ко всему не ясно, что такое value->>"$[0].value" это явно не SQL синтаксис ...

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ. П.С. value->>"$[0].value" - это новый функционал mysql 5.7 выборки данных из полей типа json

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже не знаю, что такое  value->>"$[0].value", но рискну предложить решение:

```
SELECT min(value), max(value), 
sum(case leads_fields.field_id when 244943 then -value else value end)
     FROM leads_fields, leads 
     WHERE leads_fields.field_id in(244943, 244991) 
     AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id
```

Comment: А кто сказал, что value изначально не отрицательное и еще одного из параметров может не оказаться и будет NULL. Так что лучше все таки условное вытаскивание типа `sum(if(field_id=244943,value,0))` и судя по исходному запросу явно напрашивается `group by leads.external_id`

Comment: Отнять отрицательное значение - значит прибавить. Или не так? И вообще, пока кто-то не доказал обратного, действует презумпция невиновности. :-)